# C++ Windows can't add program to startup

Tags: c++, windows

I'm using this function to add my program to startup. But it doesn't work and I don't know why weird ascii characters and words are showing up in startup applications. What am I doing wrong?

Instead this is being added to starup. `U㫅萹㐀蠀渐晁Ɉ` `U㫆萺㝈耀` `U㫆萺㝈耀` and `C`. Which has no file location and also no details.

```cpp
    HKEY NewVal;
    char loggeduser[UNLEN + 1];
    std::ostringstream fileinhome;
    GetUserNameA(loggeduser, &len);
    fileinhome << "C:\\Users\\" << loggeduser << "\\AppData\\Roaming\\snetwork\\snetwork.exe";
    std::string fp = fileinhome.str();
    const char* file = fp.c_str();
    if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), &NewVal) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (RegSetValueEx(NewVal, _T("CLI-Social-Network"), 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)file, sizeof(file)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return;
    }
    else {
        // std::cout << "Program added to Startup.\n";
        // Do nothing, Program was added to Startup
    }
    RegCloseKey(NewVal);
```

Comment: Calling the ANSI version of a Windows API, when you're dealing with string data outside your control, is *always* a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Well I removed that and added wstrings. I still cannot add it to startup and some `C` 's are being added to startup I don't know why. Really need help with this. I added `char loggeduser[UNLEN +1];
 GetUserName(loggeduser, &len);
 const size_t sizea = strlen(loggeduser) +1;
 
 std::wstring fk(sizea, L'#');
 mbstowcs(&fk[0], loggeduser, sizea);
 std::wstringstream pth;`  and passed `pth.str().c_str()` to `RegSetValueEx` but it still doesn't work and adds useless `C`'s to my startup. :(

Answer (score 0):

A possibility: You have `UNICODE` and/or `_UNICODE` defined, so `RegSetValueEx` is actually `RegSetValueExW`. Therefore, this function passes Unicode data into the buffer `file`. But `file` is an ASCII buffer, so the otherwise-valid Unicode data is incorrectly parsed as ASCII, leading to the strange output.

To fix, use `std::wstring` and `W` functions explicitly.

Unicode considerations aside, you can't use a `const char *` as a buffer for receiving data. You must allocate sufficient memory for the buffer first.

Comment: The fact that they call `GetUserNameA` with the explicit A suffix suggests that Unicode is the default (hence the need for the A override).

Comment: I still can't add the program to startup. What I'm trying to do is get the username of the Windows user and use it to create a path of a file that is located within. For example,  Get username 'bob' and then create the file's path. **C:\\Users\\bob\\AppData\\Roaming\\App\\App.exe** and add that to startup.

Comment: @EdwardKarak The thing I am getting trouble is with not adding the program to startup. But to create that path using wstring. Can you give me an example of it? Getting username as char and converting it to wstring.